# Buffer Pool Usage Percentage Query returning invalid results

Tags: mysql, buffer, information-schema

I'm trying to calculate the buffer pool usage on my database server but the query I have used in the past is giving inaccurate results:

```
mysql>     SELECT  CONCAT(FORMAT(DataPages*100.0/TotalPages,2),' %')
                            BufferPoolDataPercentage
    FROM ( SELECT  variable_value DataPages
            FROM  information_schema.global_status
            WHERE  variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data'
         ) A,
         ( SELECT  variable_value TotalPages
            FROM  information_schema.global_status
            WHERE  variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total'
         ) B;

+--------------------------+
| BufferPoolDataPercentage |
+--------------------------+
| 145.55 %                 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Can someone advise on a fix?

Comment: what is the version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: I'm using version 5.6.28 of MySQL (Percona)

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using?

Is `ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED` involved?

The changelogs say

----- 2013-02-05 5.6.10 General Availability & 2013-02-05 5.5.30 -- Functionality Added or Changed -- InnoDB -----

When compressed tables were used, the calculation to compute memory usage within the [buffer pool](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_buffer_pool) was complex because the compressed pages could be smaller than 16KB or the user-specified [page size](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_page_size). Although this information can be retrieved from the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-buffer-page-table.html) table, that operation is expensive. The following new status variables help to simplify calculations involving buffer pool memory usage:

```
[Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data), to supplement [Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data).

[Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty), to supplement [Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty](http://dev.mysql.comhttps://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty).
```

(Bug #15842637)

----- 2010-07-06 5.5.5 Developer Milestone -- Bugs Fixed -- InnoDB -----
----- 2010-05-06 5.1.47 -- Bugs Fixed -- InnoDB -----

The values of innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total and innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc in the information_schema.global_status table could be computed incorrectly. (Bug #52983)

There is a chance that your two `SELECTs` were not really done with the same data.  It *might* be safer to start with

```
SELECT  variable_value TotalPages
        FROM  information_schema.global_status
        WHERE  variable_name LIKE 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages%'
```

I checked over 150 servers, and found one other case of the anomaly you mention.

Comment: I'm using version 5.6.28 of MySQL (Percona)

Comment: @user3299633 - I doubt if it is something to worry about.  You could file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com